# Scala "or" in generic bounds

Tags: scala

I know that I can write something like this:

```
case class Something[T <: Foo with Bar](state: T)
```

This accepts classes which have the traits (or class and trait) `Foo` and `Bar`. This is an AND example where it is needed to extend both `Foo` and `Bar`. Is there an option which allows me to pass classes extending `Foo` OR `Bar` to pattern match against them?

The use case is that I have multiple Classes with different behaviors which consume states which are of shared types:

```
trait FooState
trait BarState
trait BazState

case class Foo(state: FooState) // must not accept BarState or BazState
case class Bar(state: BarState) // must not accept FooState or BazState
case class Baz(state: BazState) // must not accept FooState or BarState

case class FooBar(state: FooState or BarState) // must not accept BazState
case class FooBaz(state: FooState or BazState) // must not accept BarState
case class BarBaz(state: BarState or BazState) // must not accept FooState
```

I know I can create another trait for every compound class, but this would force me to add it to everything that extends any of these previous traits.

Comment: Could you just set the constructor of your case classes to take a variable amount of states?   `case class FooBar(states: State*)`

Comment: It would be nice to not allow taking States which are inappropriate here. Something like that would force me to patternmatch it in the constructor to detect errors as soon as possible. It's always ONE state, I just want it to be extending some of a group specified for the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would usually use a typeclass to achieve what you want, and a context bound. Here's how:

```
trait Acceptable
object Acceptable {
  implicit val fooIsGood = new Acceptable[Foo] {}
  implicit val barIsGood = new Acceptable[Bar] {}
}

case class Something[T : Acceptable](state: T)
```

And you can play with it to implement whatever functionality you want using this pattern. Achieving a real union type bound be done with `Either` or co-products, but in most scenarios this may be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is to use the `Either` type:

```
case class FooBar(state: Either[FooState, BarState]) {
  def someOperation() = {
    state match {
      case Left(fooState) => ???
      case Right(barState) => ???
    }
  }
}
```

What you've described is a union type.  The current version of Scala does not support them as you've described them, however it is planned for Dotty.

If you need more flexibility than that (more than two types for example) consider using a Coproduct from a functional programming library.  Scalaz, Cats and Shapeless all expose them.